# how to check if an electron window is closed/open on react component?

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have a multi-window app, so I want to know if a child electron window is closed or not on main window´s myComponent.tsx.

**electron.js**

```
 const childwindow= new BrowserWindow({ 
 parent: mainWindow,
        frame: false,
        transparent: true,
        resizable: false,
        ...
};
```

**myComponent.tsx**

````
 
const getChildStatus= ()=>{ 
   if (childwindow === closed){... do something}
}

  return (
    <>
     
    </>
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use `BrowserWindow.fromId(id)​` https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromidid

to get the id you should first store every window id using  : win.id  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winid-readonly

the id is readonly and is generated by electron so you can't updated so you need to store it somewhere  to use it after
examples of the array you should store :

const array =[{ name : "window1" , id : "id122333" }]

after that you can get the window using

BrowserWindow.fromId(id)

//hint you can search the window in the array using the name and not the id

Comment: How can I use this on a Tsx file?

Comment: const electron = window.require('electron');                                                             
const remote = electron.remote;
const { BrowserWindow } = remote ;                                       
 BrowserWindow.fromId(id);